# is it possible to get the most common value (String) of a column that is the result of a filter? VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a bit stuck here. I'm applying a filter in a sheet that's something like this, after applying the filter it looks like this (Example Item 999)

Item Inv. Qty Avi. Qty Flag BOX

```
999    12   9   N    X1
999    23   17  Y    X2
999    1    1   N    X14
999    21   3   N    X113
```

I was trying to get the "Flag" Column value, (inside the filter and it crashed)
Code:

```
With InventorySheet
.AutoFilterMode = False
 LRowOnQ = .Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
.Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Project
 .Range("D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=ContractNumber
 .Range("N1").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=Code
.Range("Q1").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=">0"
 Set rangeFilteredInventory = .Range("Q1:Q" & LRowOnQ)
 ControlFlag = .Range("L2").Value
 End With
```

After the filter, it always take the same value.
Code:

```
With InventorySheet
     .AutoFilterMode = False
       LRowOnQ = .Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
      .Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Project
     .Range("D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=ContractNumber
    .Range("N1").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=Code
  .Range("Q1").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=">0"
  Set rangeFilteredInventory = .Range("Q1:Q" & LRowOnQ)
End With
ControlFlag = InventorySheet.Range("L2").Value
```

Is there any way to take the most common letter of the result range? 
I'm aware there's a average option in subtotal, but I think it's just for numbers.

**EDIT**: 
Tried
Code:

```
 With InventorySheet
 .AutoFilterMode = False
 LRowOnQ = .Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
 .Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Project
 .Range("D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=ContractNumber
 .Range("N1").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=Code
 .Range("Q1").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=">0"
  Set rangeFilteredInventory = .Range("Q1:Q" & LRowOnQ)
  Set ControlRange = .Range("L1:L" & LRowOnQ)
  End With
ControlFlag = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(1, ControlRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

And it doesn't even do the loop.

Comment: Please [give credit](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) when you use code (even if modified) from [another user's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19697779/1438).  Failing to do so is disrespectful of the original author who donated their time and effort to help answer your original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved using the `MODE` function. So no need for VBA.

---

example for numbers

```
=MODE(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Range,ROW(Range)-MIN(ROW(Range)),0,1)),Range*{1,1}))
```

example for text

```
=INDEX(A3:A21,MODE(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A3,ROW(A3:A21)-ROW(A3),0)),MATCH(A3:A21,A3:A21,0)*{1,1})))
```

ctrl+shift+enter (as it's an array formula)

You can read a discussion about this [HERE](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/371589-mode-subtotal.html)

---

Here is another solution using purely VBA:

```
Public Function ModeSubTotal(rng As Range) As String
Dim Dn As Range
Dim oMax As Double
Dim K As Variant
Dim val As String

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For Each Dn In rng
            If Dn.Rows.Hidden = False Then
                If Not .Exists(Dn.Value) Then
                    .Add Dn.Value, 1
                Else
                    .Item(Dn.Value) = .Item(Dn.Value) + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
oMax = Application.Max(Application.Transpose(.Items))
For Each K In .keys
    If .Item(K) = oMax Then
        val = val & K & ","
    End If
Next K


ModeSubTotal = Left(val, Len(val) - 1)
End With
End Function
```

As it's a UDF you can use in the worksheet like a normal function:

[image: ModeSubtotal]

Or you could easily call it in code:

```
Public Sub test()

Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = ModeSubTotal(Range("C1:C20"))

End Sub
```

The function counts blanks as values at the moment, so if blank is the most occuring value that will be returned, this could be changed quite easily.

Comment: Very neat, especially because the formulas can be used whether the data is filtered or not.

Comment: Okay, but how do I do this in code? I can't directly apply it to the sheet, it needs to be done inside the module.

Comment: @Splendonia I added a pure vba alternative. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Very Helpful. I had to do some extra code after the function retuns the value, but only when the choices have the same number of appearances and it returns them all.