# Get the most common value (String) of a column that is the result of a filter? VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I found an answer about get the most common value (String) of a column with VBA as below link but I do not understand why we must transpose the .Items.

[is it possible to get the most common value (String) of a column that is the result of a filter? VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731472/is-it-possible-to-get-the-most-common-value-string-of-a-column-that-is-the-res])

```
oMax = Application.Max(Application.Transpose(.Items))
```

Can anyone explain the reason why?

I tried with both Horizontal (7 columns & 2 rows) and vertical (2 columns & 7 rows) for above code without transpose function but it is still working.

Fully code in the answer as below:

```
Public Function ModeSubTotal(rng As Range) As String
Dim Dn As Range
Dim oMax As Double
Dim K As Variant
Dim val As String

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
     .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For Each Dn In rng
           If Dn.Rows.Hidden = False Then
            If Not .Exists(Dn.Value) Then
                .Add Dn.Value, 1
            Else
                .Item(Dn.Value) = .Item(Dn.Value) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
oMax = Application.Max(Application.Transpose(.Items))
For Each K In .keys
  If .Item(K) = oMax Then
      val = val & K & ","
  End If
Next K


 ModeSubTotal = Left(val, Len(val) - 1)
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Application.Max`** function works on 1-dim **and** 2-dim arrays

> *I do not understand why we must transpose the .Items.*

Me **neither**; transposing only transforms the *"flat"* 1-dimensioned `.Items` array into a 1-based 2-dim array. `Application.Max()` works on both dimensions without changing the result regardless of a possible internal search direction :-)

*Possible background:*

In many cases one executes a double transposing of a data row with the effect to get a transposed 2-dim array first and eventually a "flat" & 1-dimensioned array in the next step as number of functions work only on a 1-dim array. Maybe this got confused in the above code.